# What are the advantages of using RL over classical approaches in problems such as collision avoidance and path planning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, comparison, path-planning, collision-avoidance

What are the advantages of going for RL based approaches than classical approaches (geometric for example) in problems such as collision avoidance and path planning?

Are RL based solutions better for adhoc replanning due to its faster execution than classical planning algorithms?

Also, if RL is supposed to be generalized solution, isn't it still based on underlying environment dynamics/map and cannot be applied to a different albeit somewhat similar environment?